# databasehandler with inner classes

Tags: java

I've tried to arranged my DatabaseHandler(outer class) so that every table in my database will be under one inner class. my code looks something like this;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "databaseName";

private static SQLiteDatabase db;

private static final String CUSTOMERS_TABLE_NAME = "customers",...;
private static final String USERS_TABLE_NAME = "users",...;
private static final String PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME = "products",...;
private static final String FORMS_TABLE_NAME = "forms",...;

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String SQL_STRING = "CREATE TABLE " + CUSTOMERS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
    .
    .
    .
    db.execSQL(SQL_STRING);
    SQL_STRING = "CREATE TABLE " + USERS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
    .
    .
    .
    db.execSQL(SQL_STRING);
    SQL_STRING = "CREATE TABLE " + PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
    .
    .
    .
    db.execSQL(SQL_STRING);
    SQL_STRING = "CREATE TABLE " + FORMS_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
    .
    .
    .
    db.execSQL(SQL_STRING);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CUSTOMERS_TABLE_NAME+" AND    "+USERS_TABLE_NAME+" AND "+PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME+" AND "+FORMS_TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

and within this class i want 4 inner classes that are represent the 4 database tables. every innerclass will hava CRUD methods. inner class for exaple;

```
public class customersHandler{
       public void createCustomer(customerStructure customer){
           .
           .
           .
        }
        public customerStructure getCustomer(String customerName){
           .
           .
           .
        }
        public void deleteCustomer(customerStructure customer){
           .
           .
           .
        }
        public int updateCustomer(customerStructure customer){
           .
           .
           .
        }
        .
        .
        .
}
```

what should i do? i declare in the main activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extande ActionBarActivity(){

DatabaseHandler db;
DatabaseHandler.customersHandler CH;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    db=new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    CH=db.new customersHandler();
    }
}
```

thats correct? what's wrong?

Comment: Pro tip: Don't build SQL like this: `"CREATE TABLE " + USERS_TABLE_NAME`. Use Prepared Statements.

Comment: how do I do this? what's the advantages of Prepared Statements?

Answer (score 0):

Create instances of the inner classes in the outer class and then define getters for them.

```
public class DatabaseHandler {
    CustomerHandler ch = new CustomerHandler();

     CustomerHandler getCustomerHandler() {
         return(ch);
     }
```

Then users get the handle and use them:

```
    DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler();
    dh.getCustomerHandler().createCustomer(customer);
```

Comment: I have tried to do this but it's doesn't work. I need to put constructor and the onCreate() and onUpgrade() methods in every inner class? I saw in videos that you need somehow to give the getApplicationContext() to the constructor.